# Null body message

Tags: bash, email

I tried to send an e-mail with attachment, the email is received with attachment but with null body message.

```
 echo -e "BODY_MSG" | mail -s "TITLE_MSG" -A runningServices.txt i********@gmail.com  < /dev/null
```

> > mail: Null message body; hope that's ok

I don't want to send body message as a file, because it is only one sentence.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't send it as an attachment if you want it to be the body. Send it to stdin of mail: `mail <options> < runningServices.txt`

Comment: Also the `echo BODY_MSG` is not resulting in the body containing "BODY_MSG" because of the /dev/null input redirection.

Comment: Thanks @jordanm: The file attached is something different than the body message, plus the code had some codes, so gmail is treating it as malicious

Comment: I added /dev/null to see the output

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is; if you wan't want a body, don't use the pipe  and just redirec from `/dev/null`. There is an option (`-E`) for explicitly preventing empty messages from being sent; what you are seeing is just a warning, not an error.

Comment: @chepner: How can I send an email without pipe? I found the code [link](https://www.tecmint.com/send-email-attachment-from-linux-commandline/)

Comment: You already are in the code you show; the `< /dev/null` overrides the pipe, so removing it won't change anything.

Comment: I found a [BUG](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=918806#22), we can fix it with `--mime`